# Adonis Many to Many, Order by 'display_order' field in relationship table

Tags: adonis.js

Due to MANY-TO-MANY relationship between `categories_1` and `categories_2`, different row in `categories_1` might show different order of `categories_2`

Example:

```
categories_1     categories_2
A                1: a , 2: b , 3: c, 4: d
B                1: c , 2: a
```

where `1:, 2: ...` are the orders.
Therefore I decide not to put the `display_order` as a field in the `categories_2` but instead put it in the relation table `categories_1_categories_2_relations` because the orders of `categories_2` depend on `categories_1`. However, by using `.with('categories_2', function(builder) {}` then `.orderBy('display_order','asc')` does not seem to allow me to read the fields in the relations table.

Is there a way that I can order the `categories_2` by using the field `display_order` in the relation table?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue... Had images in media table that can be assigned to home and order information was inside home_media table.

I solved it like this:

```
await Home.query().with('media', (builder) => {
            builder.orderBy('order', 'asc')
        })
```

But I think important thing that you missed is that I added inside my app/Models/Home.js this:

```
    media() {
    return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/Media')
        .withPivot(['type', 'order'])
}
```

So I belive .withPivot is solution for you... Just add withPivot(['display_order']) to your categories model where you defined many to many relation.

More info here: http://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/relationships#_withpivot